# Run a looped script in a screen on boot

Tags: command-line, 16.04, bash, scripts, screen

**OS: Ubuntu 16.04 x64**

I'm trying to figure out the best way of executing my shell script, which currently contains the following:

```
while true ; do php /var/www/trading/artisan stocks:update & sleep 10; done
```

Right now I have to open a `screen`, and then execute my script `sh myscript.sh`. I'd like this to automatically happen on boot preferably.

1. System boots up.
2. A `screen` is created.
3. Inside the `screen` my shell script is executed.

Thanks

Comment: Its a daemon-like job. if you are using Systemd (Ubuntu 16.04 or later), just use a service file or similar for previous systems.

Comment: See this link https://coderwall.com/p/quflrg/run-a-script-on-startup-in-a-detached-screen-on-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04, sorry. Will add to question.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this to definitely run at boot time the place your script in /etc/init.d

If you only need this to run when you login, you could place your script in /home/yourusename/.bashrc

As for executing screen, look at the manpage for definitive info on how to use screen, however I believe `screen myscript.sh` should work. Alternatively screen reads from a startup file for initialisation. Your script could be included within that file.

https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Invoking-Screen
When screen is invoked, it executes initialization commands from the files .screenrc in the user's home directory and /usr/local/etc/screenrc.